# I installed Ubuntu 20.04 as dual boot a couple days ago. I go to log into ubuntu and it says my password is incorrect

Tags: dual-boot, password

I only use one password on my home computer for all operating systems.  Unless I made a typo I missed it should work.  Any way to fix this without reinstalling?

Answer (score 0):

try this start your computer with a installation disk, and start with recovery mode! Then you are logged like root. You need to use passwd command for change the password for user.

`passwd {user}`